# Google translate text to speech and apostrophes

Tags: google-translate, google-text-to-speech

I am using google API to translate a sentence. Once translated I use text to speech google API with the result of the translation. 
Translation and text to speech work pretty well in general. However, I have a problem with the apostrophes.  For example:

- 1) Translation result:  I & # 3 9 ; m tired  (Note: I had to separate the characters with spaces because it was shown as "I´m tired" in the preview...
- 2) Text to speech result says : "I and hash thirty nine m tired" (or something similar)

What kind of encoding do I need to use in the 1st step to get the output string right (i.e. I´m tired) 
The program is in python. I include an extract here:

```
 def tts_translated_text (self, input_text, input_language):

         from google.cloud import texttospeech

         client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
         input_text = input_text.encode ("utf-8")
         # Set the text input to be synthesized
         synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=input_text)
         voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams( language_code=input_language, ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

         audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
               audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)

         response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

         # The response's audio_content is binary.
         with open('output.wav', 'wb') as out:
            # Write the response to the output file.
         out.write(response.audio_content)
```

Thanks in advance,
Ester

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong. Google Translate API returns the string with HTML encoding. And Google Text-To-Speech expects UTF-8 encoding.
I am forced to use python2.7 so I did the following:

```
 translated_text = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape (translated_text_html)
```

Where translated_text_html is the returned string from the translation API invocation

In python3 it should be:

```
 translated_text = html.unescape (translated_text_html)
```